# Primitive cast and assignments in Java

Tags: java, casting, primitive

Why the following works

> ```
> float f = 10l // OK  32 bits to 64 ?
> ```

float is only 32 bits and long 64 bits so there is NO room for float in the long

and this one doesn't

> ```
> long l = 10f    //compile error
> ```

Could someone explain to me how kind of casting works?

Comment: Long is whole number, so a float of 10l can be a long

Comment: JLS [Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Comment: just to clarify concept of casting. I need to pass ocjp 6 exam.

Comment: You can "widen" a type without a cast. float is considered wider than a long due to the wider range of values it can have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion from `long` to `float` is specifically allowed for assignment by the [JLS, Section 5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - byte to short, int, long, float, or double
> - short to int, long, float, or double
> - char to int, long, float, or double
> - int to long, float, or double
> - long to float or double
> - float to double

And

> A widening primitive conversion from int to float, or from long to float, or from long to double, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode (§4.2.4).

So, the range of values is covered, but there may be a loss of precision.  That is allowed and expected.

The other line:

```
long l = 10f;
```

is a [primitive narrowing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3), which the [JLS, Section 5.2 "Assignment Contexts"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), doesn't specifically allow:

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

Note that an explicit cast would allow the narrowing primitive conversion.

```
long l = (long) 10f; // Compiles
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for documentation on [widening primitive conversions, and narrowing primitive conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

`long` to `float` is a widening conversion, and `float` to `long` is a narrowing conversion.

In general, widening conversions are safe because what you're converting to can always take whatever value the narrower type might be dishing out.   Narrowing conversions are **not** always safe, because you could destroy information or end up with `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

The first initialization is a [widening primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

The second initialization is a [narrowing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3). Loss of information may occur. Consider what would happen if you tried to assign `long l = 10.5f` - the integral type could not represent the fractional part.